# How to add Vue to an existing Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have an existing laravel project and am looking to change only one part of the site to use Vue for the views. What is the best approach here because most of the info I've seen on Laravel + Vue is how to start a project from scratch but this would be an existing project. Please, someone, suggest me a tutorial for this. Thank you.

Comment: What part of it are you struggling with the most at the minute? Are you looking to create an SPA or are you just wanting to create components for various parts of the site that you can drop into your blade files?

Comment: do you need use only one page or many pages ?

Comment: Yeah am looking to create a SPA and I cannot find a proper way to do it. Please suggest me some tuts to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Currently, I have blade files, I need to change those to Vue components and to create a SPA. All the tutorials are starting from scratch and it is difficult for me to go with those tutorials as I am new to Vue.

Comment: when you talk about SPA you need to change everything from the scratch so just check this -https://codebriefly.com/basic-laravel-vue-js-setup/

Comment: I found this tutorial but I cannot watch it for free: https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/enhance-your-laravel-app-with-vuejs, hoping for a better tutorial as this. Thank you.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step

Comment: https://inertiajs.com/

Comment: Thank you very much @Rwd, really I was looking for something like this. And I never heard about the inertia library before, thanks again for the suggestion. I'll try this.

Comment: @Hamerlraj, It will be used on many pages.